# jQuery Selectbox issue with latest chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectbox

**Issue with chrome 35 version**
While loading drop down using jQuery Selectbox, i am facing an issue in chrome 35. 
Even after minimizng the drop down, there are lot of lines remaining. On clicking somewhere else it vanishes.

The issue is not avaialble in version 33.PFA the images. 
[image: Print screen with extra lines]

While closing  jquery select box leaves the **blue horizontal lines** in the window.Any suggestions or pointers is appreciated

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I added an upvote to balance it out again.

Comment: @xero: don't. Upvote if you feel the question is useful by all means; but don't do it just for sympathy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue outline comes from the UA stylesheet. The default is:

```
:focus {
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

Add this somewhere in your CSS to override it:

```
.sbHolder:focus {outline: none;}
```